# Replace dot with comma Input while typing decimal points

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am using react hooks, and I want to achieve the following, replacing a dot with a comma while a using is typing in the Input text box. Below is my code :

```
const formatDecimal = (value: number) => Number(value).toLocaleString('de-DE');

  const onChange = useCallback(
    event => {
      const { value } = event.target;
      // @ts-ignore
      const newValue = formatDecimal(value)
      setFieldValue(name, newValue);
    },
    [setFieldValue, name],
  );
```

It doesn't work as expected, it only doesn't show the comma, whenever I type the dot.

Comment: I would suggest using some library for that purpose, there are multiple caveats you don't see now. For example, type `123456` it gets transformed to `123,456`, but if you then type a number after the `3` and want to delete, it would delete the `,`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regex and String#replace function

```js
const replaceDotWithComma = str => {
  return str.replace(/\./g, ',');
}

console.log(replaceDotWithComma('12.567'))
console.log(replaceDotWithComma('30.6'))
```

This is for the input field, you can do the reverse before saving the value as float.

Comment: With this I can't seem to type `30.6` to show `30,6` , it stops on `30,0`

Comment: And surprisingly it shows `30.0` after typing , is it because of the `onChange`

Comment: In the example, it shows 30,6 as expected. Why are you using a callback on the onChange function?

Comment: It helps me to keep track of the values set `setFieldValue`

Comment: Well, what you asked is answered, idk why you get 30,0 in your case. Not reproducible unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

The problem with different region the number display can changed `.toLocaleString('de-DE')` so The best case should use the library to do it

http://numeraljs.com/